# NFS mount connectivity status location in Centos

Tags: centos, nfs

Centos server that establishes a NFS mount on bootup using /etc/fstab, NOT automount.
I assume there was a network issue between the two servers that caused the one to drop its mount. After a successful ping, a few days later, the mount reappeared. 
My question therefore is where does Centos keep the fact that the remote location is not reachable, so that I can find this information while troubleshooting? /var/log/messages did not have any information, nor dmesg.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something in `/var/log/boot.log`. If your boot.log empty, take a look at: http://oracle4newbies.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/empty-blank-boot-log-problem-in-fedora-centos-as-well-as-oel-2/